# SOAP 1.1 encodingStyle attribute validation error

Tags: soap, xml-validation, xsd-validation

Looking at the SOAP 1.1 specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/) and the corresponding XSD (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/), I can see a mismatch regarding `encodingStyle` attribute.

There are many examples in this W3C note, showing the usage of `encodingStyle` attribute, e.g.:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
       <m:GetLastTradePrice xmlns:m="Some-URI">
           <symbol>DIS</symbol>
       </m:GetLastTradePrice>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Furthermore, section 4.1.1 says:

```
The SOAP encodingStyle global attribute can be used to indicate the serialization rules 
used in a SOAP message. This attribute MAY appear on any element, and is scoped to that
element's contents and all child elements not themselves containing such an attribute, 
much as an XML namespace declaration is scoped.
```

However, the XSD **does not allow** to use the `encodingStyle` attribute within the envelope nor header elements:

```
<xs:complexType name="Envelope">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="tns:Header" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element ref="tns:Body" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

As you can see, there is an XSD wildcard *"##other"*, saying that any attribute is allowed from OTHER THAN target namespace. However, the target namespace in the example is the same, so that the example *should not be valid*. Also doing a quick test can verify this: trying to validate the xml document containing this soap example will result in failure (tested in Intellij Idea).

**Can anybody tell me**, whether there is a bug in the W3C note, in the XSD, or am I missing something? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a WG error to me; given that WG members are more likely to have looked at, and understood, the examples in the note than they are to have looked at, or understood, the XSD schema document, my money would have to be on "error in the XSD".  (But I wasn't there; I'm just speculating based on the way WGs tend to behave under time pressure.)